# Android: passing parameters between classes

Tags: android, parameters, android-intent

I have a **class2** which is involved by **class1** when clicks are made. I have to pass some parameters/objects from **class1** to **class2**. I only know the standard way which does not have an option of passing parameters.

```
// launch the full article
Intent i = new Intent(this, Class2.class);

startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Intent.putExtra` (Which uses a `Bundle`) to pass extra data.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Class2.class);
i.putExtra("foo", 5.0f);
i.putExtra("bar", "baz");
startActivity(i);
```

Then once you're inside your new `Activity`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null)
{
 float foo = extras.getFloat("foo");
 String bar = extras.getString("bar");
}
```

This allows you to pass basic data to Activities.  However, you may need a bit more work for passing arbitrary objects along.

Comment: which means only simple types (int, String, double) can be passed but not Classes? Even BigMap cannot be passed?

Comment: You can pass serializable and "parcelable" objects along, too.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

I'll look around to see what I can find on making passing objects easier.  One consideration is to make a static field on the activity class that you can set to the reference of the object before starting the activity.