# How do you pass a float[] array between activities in android?

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent

class1.java has creates a float[] array that is need to have in class2.java. How do you do this? The float[] is points. Here is an example code:

```
class1.java

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.view.Display;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class class1 extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            float[] points = new float[100];
            }
    }


class2.java



 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Path;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class graph extends Activity{

     DemoView demoview;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            demoview = new DemoView(this);
            setContentView(demoview);

     }
     private class DemoView extends View{
      public DemoView(Context context){
       super(context);
      }

      @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas);

       canvas.drawLines(points, paint);

      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Re-tagged with the language and parameter-passing which is closer to what the question is asking.

Comment: If you retagged this as java, then you're probably doing a disservice. This is very much an android question.

Comment: @Falmarri: The extension is .JAVA in the OP's question and code.

Comment: @Evan - but this isn't a java question, per se, it is an android implementation of java question.

Answer (score 3):

Update to an old question, but it might help someone.

Pass it using an `Intent`. In class1:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), class2.class);
i.putExtra("points",points);            
startActivity(i);
```

In class2:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
float[] points = extras.getFloatArray("points");
```

Refer to the API for [bundles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to see what other structures can be sent

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is more difficult than first appearances as it's not a java problem but an android problem.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582690/android-passing-paramters-between-classes) for more information

Comment: @Falmarri - if this won't work, what will? (note - I edited my answer with more android specific pointers)

Comment: the link you have in the edit does contain the correct answer.  The part you have before that does't realy make any sense in the Android setting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, there are two (maybe more) ways:

1) Pass the `float[]` in the constructor of class2. (Given your code, this probably isn't the best way.)

2) Create a method `setMyFloatArray(float[] arr)` in class2 and a `getMyFloatArray()` method in class1. After instantiating class1 and class2 in your program, call the set method with the get method as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

For that you may use `String` extras passed along with the `Intent`.

So, first of all you need to get a `String` representation of your float[] array:

```
public class YourArrayUtils {

    public static String pack(float[] data) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final int length = data.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            sb.append(data[i]);
            if (i < (length - 1)) {
                sb.append(':');
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static float[] unpack(String str) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
            return new float[0]; // or null depending on your needs
        } else {
            String[] srtData = TextUtils.split(str, ":");
            final int length = srtData.length;
            float[] result = new float[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                result[i] = Float.parseFloat(srtData[i]);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Then pass it along with `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivityA.this, YourActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("floatArray", YourArrayUtils.pack(yourFloatArray));
startActivity(i);
```

And finally in YourActivityB extract it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    Intent i = getIntent(); // get starting Intent
    float[] yourFloatArray = YourArrayUtils.unpack(i.getStringExtra("floatArray"));
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass data around in a Global Singleton if it is going to be used a lot.

```
public class YourApplication extends Application 
{     
     public float[] points = new float[100];
}
```

Then call it in any activity by:

```
YourApplication appState = ((YourApplication)this.getApplication());
appState.points = new float[100]; // Do whatever you need to with the points here.
```

Comment: Really?  A public global variable?  That seems like a really bad idea.  At the very minimum you should use a getter, in case you someday want to change that array to a list, or something else.

Comment: @Mayra it was merely an example of how to access a global singleton, the implementation is up to the reader.  I condensed it for the sake of readability.  It is better to setup a class as the global object that has yes, accessor and setters.  For a more clearcut example, see my blog post here, heading "Global Singletons" http://www.bryandenny.com/index.php/2010/05/25/what-i-learned-from-writing-my-first-android-application/  You can't pass such complex data via intents, so you have to do this or use a database or similar.