# Hidden field in ListView to pass a variable

Tags: android, variables, listview, android-activity, android-intent

I'm trying to build my first application which pretty much creates a list from an XML file on the net. as soon as i click on a list item it should open another activity and access another online generated XML file with the details for the item.
ive managed to get the list working aswell as the 2nd activity window with the details. the only thing thats left to do is to pass the id from one activity to another.
is there a way to store the ID of each entry in the list items? im not using a local SQLite db or anything, so i need to find a way to do this "on the fly" if possible
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks i got it to work!!
here is the code just in case someone has the same problem:

```
package en.android.itleaked.com;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class getReleases extends Activity {
    public ListView lv1;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getFeed();

    }


    public void getFeed() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.it-leaked.com/app/main.php");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            String lv_arr[] = new String[nodeList.getLength()];
            final String lv_arr_id[] = new String[nodeList.getLength()];  
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("title");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                lv_arr[i] = ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue();

                NodeList idList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("id");
                Element idElement = (Element) idList.item(0);
                idList = idElement.getChildNodes();
                lv_arr_id[i] = ((Node) idList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
            }

            lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));

            lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(getReleases.this, showReleases.class);
                            i.putExtra("id", lv_arr_id[position]);
                            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
                    }
            });


        }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

}
```

And here is the receiving end:

```
package en.android.itleaked.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class showReleases extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.releasedetails);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String releaseid = extras.getString("id");
            Toast.makeText(this, releaseid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be doing your network calls in a separate thread. Consider yourself lucky if you've never seen the "application has not responded" window

Answer (score 1):

Your list should live on a model for data, and once a user clicks a row you should be mapping that location to a point in your model. If you want to just hack this together you can use [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) on views to store any type of object. This is not a traditional use of this function. If you post how you are creating the the listview it might be more helpful.

After looking at your code you will probably want to do something like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
Intent i = new Intent(getReleases.this, showReleases.class);
i.putExtra("id", lv_arr[position]);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}
```

Check out [Passing Extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582690/android-passing-paramters-between-classes) on how to use putExtra().

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply! here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/DJgThn0S
the xml is being generated at http://www.it-leaked.com/app/main.php
what i want is to be able to pass the ID to the showReleases activity so i can grab xml from there the same way and generate the content on the server...for example http://www.it-leaked.com/app/release.php?id=45325
i hope you can help me out cause i am new to this and it already took me 2 days to get this working so far