# Android how to pass prams to search intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: passing paramters between classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582690/android-passing-paramters-between-classes)

I have an activity which search intent has to have different logic depending on params which is passed to it. The question is how to pass these params into search intent?

Then after starting activity I call Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(getIntent().getAction()) and depending on params passed I have to do certain actions.

If I understand correctly Android system starts Search. and every messages to intent could be passed only by system, is it proper understanding?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582690/android-passing-paramters-between-classes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can do it through overriding method onSearchRequested()

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    Bundle appData = new Bundle();
    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFavorites", false) == false){
        appData.putBoolean("isSearchFavorites", false);
    } else {
        appData.putBoolean("isSearchFavorites", true);
    }
    startSearch(null, false, appData, false);
    return true;
}
```

In its turn this method invokes methos startSearch which can pass parameters to Search Intent.